# getting command not found when middleman is called

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, middleman

Hi I have installed ruby in my ubuntu 16.04 and successfully installed, and also installed middleman to check my project its worked properly, when I reconnect to middleman I got error middleman: command not found I am not getting what the mistake is. when I try to re initialise it, it asks to install ruby. please help someone to know the exact error.

```
  urujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ cd sunil
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/sunil$ atom .
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/sunil$ middleman
middleman: command not found
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/sunil$ middleman
middleman: command not found
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/sunil$ middleman init
middleman: command not found
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/sunil$ cd Home
bash: cd: Home: No such file or directory
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/sunil$ cd..
cd..: command not found
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/sunil$ cd ..
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ cd Home
bash: cd: Home: No such file or directory
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ mkdir example
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ cd example
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/example$ middleman init
middleman: command not found
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/example$ cd ..
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ gem install middleman
The program 'gem' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ sudo apt install ruby
[sudo] password for gurujada: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-lato javascript-common libjs-jquery libruby2.3 rake ruby-did-you-mean
  ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit ruby2.3
  rubygems-integration
Suggested packages:
  apache2 | lighttpd | httpd ri ruby-dev bundler
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-lato javascript-common libjs-jquery libruby2.3 rake ruby
  ruby-did-you-mean ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert
  ruby-test-unit ruby2.3 rubygems-integration
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,042 kB of archives.
After this operation, 27.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 fonts-lato all 2.0-1 [2,693 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 javascript-common all 11 [6,066 B]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libjs-jquery all 1.11.3+dfsg-4 [161 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 rubygems-integration all 1.10 [4,966 B]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ruby-did-you-mean all 1.0.0-2 [8,390 B]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ruby-minitest all 5.8.4-2 [36.6 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ruby-net-telnet all 0.1.1-2 [12.6 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ruby-power-assert all 0.2.7-1 [7,668 B]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ruby-test-unit all 3.1.7-2 [60.3 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libruby2.3 amd64 2.3.1-2~16.04 [2,957 kB]
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ruby2.3 amd64 2.3.1-2~16.04 [40.9 kB]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ruby all 1:2.3.0+1 [5,530 B]
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 rake all 10.5.0-2 [48.2 kB]
Fetched 6,042 kB in 25s (239 kB/s)                                             
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-lato.
(Reading database ... 211722 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fonts-lato_2.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-lato (2.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package javascript-common.
Preparing to unpack .../javascript-common_11_all.deb ...
Unpacking javascript-common (11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjs-jquery.
Preparing to unpack .../libjs-jquery_1.11.3+dfsg-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libjs-jquery (1.11.3+dfsg-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rubygems-integration.
Preparing to unpack .../rubygems-integration_1.10_all.deb ...
Unpacking rubygems-integration (1.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby-did-you-mean.
Preparing to unpack .../ruby-did-you-mean_1.0.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking ruby-did-you-mean (1.0.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby-minitest.
Preparing to unpack .../ruby-minitest_5.8.4-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking ruby-minitest (5.8.4-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby-net-telnet.
Preparing to unpack .../ruby-net-telnet_0.1.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking ruby-net-telnet (0.1.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby-power-assert.
Preparing to unpack .../ruby-power-assert_0.2.7-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ruby-power-assert (0.2.7-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby-test-unit.
Preparing to unpack .../ruby-test-unit_3.1.7-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking ruby-test-unit (3.1.7-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libruby2.3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libruby2.3_2.3.1-2~16.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby2.3.
Preparing to unpack .../ruby2.3_2.3.1-2~16.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ruby2.3 (2.3.1-2~16.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby.
Preparing to unpack .../ruby_1%3a2.3.0+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ruby (1:2.3.0+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rake.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/rake_10.5.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking rake (10.5.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up fonts-lato (2.0-1) ...
Setting up javascript-common (11) ...
Setting up libjs-jquery (1.11.3+dfsg-4) ...
Setting up rubygems-integration (1.10) ...
Setting up ruby-did-you-mean (1.0.0-2) ...
Setting up ruby-minitest (5.8.4-2) ...
Setting up ruby-net-telnet (0.1.1-2) ...
Setting up ruby-power-assert (0.2.7-1) ...
Setting up ruby-test-unit (3.1.7-2) ...
Setting up libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04) ...
Setting up ruby2.3 (2.3.1-2~16.04) ...
Setting up ruby (1:2.3.0+1) ...
Setting up rake (10.5.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ gem install middleman
Fetching: bundler-1.12.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ cd example
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/example$ middleman init
middleman: command not found
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/example$ cd ..
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.3 /usr/lib/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
gurujada@gurujada-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

From your log:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

Middleman was not successfully installed because your user can't write to the directory it should be installed in.

You have two easy options:

1. run `sudo gem install middleman`
2. run `sudo gem install bundler`, and then in your project directory, create a Gemfile with the following content:

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org"

   gem "middleman", "~> 4.1"
   ```

   and run `bundle install` in the project directory.

You should really do option 2 so you can keep multiple version of gems installed.

You could also not use the system Ruby and install one yourself with RVM or rbenv, but that is a little more work.

Comment: I installed ruby with RVM not used the system ruby

Comment: You probably used `sudo` somewhere in installing RVM or the ruby. That's the problem.